# Fill cells that match a certain condition, but the condition is defined based on already filled rows

Tags: r, dataframe, na

I have the following data set:

```
  hs desc
1 34    a
2 53    b
3 64    c
4 54    d
5 34 <NA>
6 34 <NA>
7 53 <NA>
8 53    b
9 53    b
10 53 <NA>
```

First of all, in an ideal world, everytime `hs` has a certain value, `desc` should match with another value. For example: everytime you see 34 on `hs`, you should see "a" on desc. But as you can see from my dataset, it has a lot of `NA`s. I need to fill these cells with the corresponding values based `hs` codes.

It may appear simple from the start. I could use `ifelse` or `dplyr::case_when`. But that's not enough, because my real database has A LOT of different `hs` codes

The code I need should do this:

1. It should see the filled cells and understand that everytime a `hs` has a certain value, desc should have a corresponding value
2. But the code should do this based on the already filled values. I'm not telling my code explicitly that if `hs`=34, then `desc`="a". He knows it by itself after scanning my dataset
3. Once the code itself knows what desc should be based on `hs`, then it should fill all `NA`s appropriately.

For example:

1. The code scans my dataset and sees, in any already filled row, that if `hs`=34, then `desc`="a".
2. After that, the code should put `desc`=a everytime he sees `hs`=34

I know it's confusing, but I hope someone understands me.

Comment: Hi, if this issue is solved, you can consider accepting one of the answers you prefer by clicking the check mark.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `fill()` from `tidyr` by groups.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(hs) %>%
  fill(desc, .direction = "downup") %>%
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 10 × 2
#       hs desc 
#    <int> <chr>
#  1    34 a    
#  2    53 b    
#  3    64 c    
#  4    54 d    
#  5    34 a    
#  6    34 a    
#  7    53 b    
#  8    53 b    
#  9    53 b    
# 10    53 b
```

##### Data

```r
df <- read.table(text = "  hs desc
1 34    a
2 53    b
3 64    c
4 54    d
5 34 <NA>
6 34 <NA>
7 53 <NA>
8 53    b
9 53    b
10 53 <NA> ", na.strings = "<NA>")
```

Comment: Looks like it worked. Thank you! It's funny, because I tried a similar approach earlier and it did not work back then. Maybe I was missing something!

Answer (score 3):

Since for each `desc` only one `hs` value is present, you could simply mutate and take the `max`, `min`, or anything by `hs`.

`df |> mutate(desc = max(desc), .by = hs)`

```
   hs desc
1  34    a
2  53    b
3  64    c
4  54    d
5  34    a
6  34    a
7  53    b
8  53    b
9  53    b
10 53    b
```

Answer (score 2):

You can first `filter` your original dataframe to exclude `NA`, this will be your "reference" dataframe. Then `left_join` your original dataframe to this reference dataframe for filling the `NA`.

```r
library(dplyr)

left_join(
  df |> select(hs),
  df |> 
    filter(!is.na(desc)) |> 
    distinct(),
  by = "hs"
)

   hs desc
1  34    a
2  53    b
3  64    c
4  54    d
5  34    a
6  34    a
7  53    b
8  53    b
9  53    b
10 53    b
```

Comment: It did not work. It says:   Detected an unexpected many-to-many
relationship between `x` and `y`.
ℹ Row 1 of `x` matches multiple rows in `y`.
ℹ Row 1 of `y` matches multiple rows in `x`.
ℹ If a many-to-many relationship is expected,
  set `relationship = "many-to-many"` to
  silence this warning.

Comment: @PedroCardoso Are all of your hs-desc pairs unique? i.e. will multiple `hs` values mapped to the same `desc`? If you have more than two columns, please try my updated version to only `select` hs.

Comment: Yes, any hs value is mapped to the same desc. If hs is "x", desc is strictly "y", with the exception of NAs rows obviously.

Comment: @PedroCardoso Then I guess you have more than two columns in your dataframe. I hope it worked using my updated code, but Darren's answer is certainly way better.